# Usar Django con una bases de datos Sql Sever existente

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Estoy tratando de probar Django con una base de datos en Sql Server que ya existe.

He buscado documentación, y todo apunta a usar el comando `Inspectdb` (`python mysite/manage.py inspectdb > mysite/myapp/models.py`).

Esto no me funciona, igualmente la documentación menciona la configuración a nivel de `settings.py` (Engine - Name- User - Password) en el apartado "Databases".

¿Alguien podría por favor orientarme al respecto? ¿Algún testimonio de aplicaciones desarrolladas en Django contra Sql Server?

Comment: Hola, ¿por qué no funciona el inspect?, ¿te da algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalar

```
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.0.0
pyodbc==4.0.17

Y en settings
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Nombre de la BDD ',
        'USER':'usuario',
        'PASSWORD':'contraseña',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'1433',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver':'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',
            #Depende del driver de SQL---https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662123/pyodbc-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-paradox
           }
    }
}
```